# Como persistir valor do $_SESSION no <select> assim como foi feito para o <input>?

Tags: php, formulário, session

Estou tentando pegar o valor do `select` no `$_SESSION` para persistir os dados da busca em um sistema que estou fazendo, mas não sei aplicar este método para o `select`. Podem me ajudar?

Vou guardar as variáveis depois do `$_POST`...

```
<?php 

if($_POST) {
    $_SESSION['nome'] = $_POST['nome'];
}

?>
```

> Como guardar o `select` assim como guardei o `input`?

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['nome'])){
    echo '<input type="text" name="nome" value="'.$_SESSION['nome'].'" class="form-control">';
} else {
    echo '<input type="text" name="nome" value="" class="form-control">';
}
?>
<select name="tipo" class="form-control" required>
    <option value="">Tipo</option>
    <option value="apartamento">Apartamento</option>
    <option value="casa">Casa</option>
    <option value="flat">Flat</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se eu entendi a pergunta, é mais ou menos isso:

```
<?php
   $s = ' selected="selected" ';
   $nome = isset( $_SESSION['nome'] ) ? $_SESSION['nome'] : '';
   $tipo = isset( $_SESSION['tipo'] ) ? $_SESSION['tipo'] : '';
?>
<input type="text" name="nome" value="" class="form-control">
<select name="tipo" class="form-control" required>
    <option value="">Tipo</option>
    <option <?php echo $tipo=='apartamento'?$s:''; ?>value="apartamento">Apartamento</option>
    <option <?php echo $tipo=='casa'       ?$s:''; ?>value="casa">Casa</option>
    <option <?php echo $tipo=='flat'       ?$s:''; ?>value="flat">Flat</option>
</select>
```

Ou seja, apenas a opção selecionada anteriormente vai receber o parâmetro `selected`.

Se precisar verificar o post, fica assim o código completo:

```
<?php
   session_start();
   if( isset( $_POST['nome'] ) ) $_SESSION['nome'] = $_POST['nome'];
   if( isset( $_POST['tipo'] ) ) $_SESSION['tipo'] = $_POST['tipo'];

   $s = ' selected="selected" ';
   $nome = isset( $_SESSION['nome'] ) ? $_SESSION['nome'] : '';
   $tipo = isset( $_SESSION['tipo'] ) ? $_SESSION['tipo'] : '';
?>
<input type="text" name="nome" value="" class="form-control">
<select name="tipo" class="form-control" required>
    <option value="">Tipo</option>
    <option <?php echo $tipo=='apartamento'?$s:''; ?>value="apartamento">Apartamento</option>
    <option <?php echo $tipo=='casa'       ?$s:''; ?>value="casa">Casa</option>
    <option <?php echo $tipo=='flat'       ?$s:''; ?>value="flat">Flat</option>
</select>
```

Comment: É exatamente isso !!!! Os caminhos da outra resposta me ajudou a chegar aonde queria. Obrigado.

Comment: Eu achei boa a explicação do Alisson, mas tive impressão que sua pergunta era mais sobre o select do que sobre o session.

Comment: Vou fazer esta pergunta para checkbox ... me ajuda Bacco ... Obrigado !!!

Comment: Errei o termo ... é checkbox porque envolve ***array*** e seleção de vários elementos ... por isso quero reproduzir essa pergunta para checkbox. O que acha?

Answer (score 3):

É a mesma forma do `$_POST['nome']` só alterando o valor.

**Tente**

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST)) {
    $_SESSION['nome'] = $_POST['nome'];
    $_SESSION['tipo'] = $_POST['tipo'];
}
```

Não se esqueça de colocar `session_start()` no começo do código para iniciar a sessão.

Para verificar se existe

```
<?php

if(!empty($_SESSION['tipo'])){
     echo 'existe';
}else{
     echo 'não existe';
}
```

Comment: Pode incrementar a resposta adicionando o ***if/else*** no `select` pra eu ver a estrutura?

Comment: @MarcosVinicius desculpe, não entendi a pergunta

Comment: Viu que eu fiz o ***if/else*** no `input` pra detectar se existe valor na session `nome` ... Gostaria de saber como é feito isso no `select` !!! Obrigado

Comment: Pronto @MarcosVinicius . Eu usei a função `empty` para verificar se a sessão não está vazia, pois as vezes ela pode ser criada e ter seu valor vazio, então a empty faz essa verificação. É basicamente quase igual a `isset`

Comment: Como isso pode ser melhorado? Quem visitar esse pergunta, este link é uma versão funcional para armazenar campos de uma busca - http://pastebin.com/XizWNWbh

Comment: Uma dica é você colocar os inputs com `required` para não ter chance do usuário não digitar nada e mesmo assim quando clicar no botão do submit ele gravar a `session` vazia. Outra coisa, uma dica também, é no submit você colocar o `name` dele e no IF invez de verificar só `if($_POST)` verificar assim `if($_POST['nome_do_sumit'])` . Acho mais seguro fazer essa forma, pois assim você sabe que ele clicou realmente no botão.

Comment: Estou aprendendo isso hoje. Muito obrigado pela ajuda. :)