# Select checked ao voltar

Tags: php, html

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<p>Status</p>
<select id="st" name="st" value="<?php echo $DsStatus; ?>" />
    <option value="0">➖</option>
    <option value="1">➖⬆</option>
    <option value="2">➖⬇</option>
    <option value="3">↑➖</option>
    <option value="4">↓➖</option>
    <option value="5">↑⬇</option>
    <option value="6">↓⬆</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" class="round success button" value="Aplicar"/>
```

Preciso que após eu clicar no submit(aplicar) e voltar para a page do select ele fique selecionado na option que eu marquei quando dei submit(aplicar).

Comment: como assim  voltar para a page do select?

Comment: Você está querendo fazer um autorefresh com submit correto?

Comment: Vou dar submit ele vai sair dessa page, ira ir para outra, só preciso que quando eu volte ele pegue o valor que foi salvo. Essa pagina é uma pagina que edita informações por isso preciso.

Comment: Pode fazer com ajax ou, verificar se o `$_POST` existe, e fazer uns if se o valor enviado é igual ao da option, e colocar o `selected="selected"`

Comment: Pode se basear por : http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106370/91

Comment: simples, usa $_SESSION

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para isso, você precisa devolver o valor selecionado para a page do select, suponhamos que você devolva na variável `$selecionado`

```
$selecionado = $_REQUEST['st'];
```

Na página, você aplica a seguinte alteração para saber quem foi selecionado:

```
<p>Status</p>
<select id="st" name="st" value="<?php echo $DsStatus; ?>" />
    <option value="0" <?= $selecionado == 0 ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>➖</option>
    <option value="1" <?= $selecionado == 1 ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>➖⬆</option>
    <option value="2" <?= $selecionado == 2 ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>➖⬇</option>
    <option value="3" <?= $selecionado == 3 ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>↑➖</option>
    <option value="4" <?= $selecionado == 4 ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>↓➖</option>
    <option value="5" <?= $selecionado == 5 ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>↑⬇</option>
    <option value="6" <?= $selecionado == 6 ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>↓⬆</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" class="round success button" value="Aplicar"/>
```

`<?= $selecionado == 0 ? 'selected' : ''; ?>` é um `if ternário` que significa a mesma coisa que

```
if ($selecionado == 0) {
    echo 'selected';
} else {
    echo '';
}
```

Comment: É certo usar $_REQUEST?

Comment: @TiagoP.C Depende do caso, eu usei no exemplo porque não sabia se o form era POST ou GET, mas o [$_REQUEST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) junta $_POST, $_GET e $_COOKIES.

Comment: O form é um $_POST, porém não encaixei esse $_REQUEST muito bem.

Comment: Mas assim funcionou.

Comment: @Kevin.F pode usar `$_POST['st']` no lugar então.

Answer (score 2):

Pode fazer duas consultas e fazer uma comparação.

```
<?php
$sql="SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE id= $id";  
$resultado = $conexao->query($sql);
while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {

$st_selected = $row['st']
}

$sql="SELECT st FROM tabela  ORDER BY st";  
  $resultado= $conexao->query($sql);
while($row= $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
   $st = $row['st'];

if($st  == $st_selected){
    $select='selected';
}else{
    $select=''; 
?>
<select id="st" name="st"  />
<?php
     echo '<option value="$st_selected" '.$select.'>$st_selected</option>';
    } 
?>

    <option value="0">➖</option>
    <option value="1">➖⬆</option>
    <option value="2">➖⬇</option>
    <option value="3">↑➖</option>
    <option value="4">↓➖</option>
    <option value="5">↑⬇</option>
    <option value="6">↓⬆</option>
</select>
```